# Calculate the average of values for a variable number of coordinates in a fixed interval

Tags: r, aggregate

I want to calculate the mean for the values (column 2) of the coordinates (column 1) for a fixed interval (e.g. 2). However, the number of coordinates having a value is variable. I would like to try different size of window too.

Data example (tab separated)

```
2  3
2  4
2  5
3  1
4  2
5  1
5  2
6  8
```

Desired output for window of size 2 (we move every two X-values)

```
x  mean  window
2  3.25  2-3
3  3.25  2-3
4  1.66  4-5
5  1.66  4-5
6  8     6-7
```

Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: Maybe I'm dopey today, but what is the relationship between the data and the desired output? It is not clear to me.

Comment: The idea is to have the average of the values for each position(first column), I'm sorry if it wasn't too clear.

Comment: The desired output doesn't seem related to the example data, is I think what thelatemail is getting at. You should fix that, if only to avoid confusion.

Comment: This is a fairly basic R question. I would suggest reading http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html. For your question look at the apply functions, by or aggregate. And as others have noted your output is incorrect for the data and the desired computation that you explain.

Comment: @LeonLara - to start you off, assuming your data is called `test` and your columns are `one` and `two`, then you could do: `aggregate(two ~ one, data=test, FUN=mean)`

Comment: The data is correct. Each value in the first column represents a position in the X-axis and the second column is the Y-axis value associated to each first column value. However, each position can have more than one value associated, so it will be repeated and showing a different (or the same) value in the second column. So what I want is to be able to calculate the average of the Y-axis values in a fixed interval, e.g. for 2/3, 2/4,2/5, and 3/1, the calculated values should be 2/3.25 and 3/3.25. This interval of "2" X-values sometimes can have more values, e.g., for the 6-7 interval

Comment: Ah, so you want the average across two x-values, which may contain multiple y-values.

Comment: @amon that's correct, I'm sorry ... there's always a way to write everything in a more efficient way

Comment: @LeonLara I just add labels and a new window column to your desired output to clarify your idea. I hope I am not wrong? +1 I think it is a good question not nicely asked

Comment: @agstudy - I'd argue that is a window of `2` not `1` in your edit.

Comment: @thelatemail it depends I think. I would say in a signal processing it is a window of size 1 (the gap of the interval)..Maybe LeonLara can edit it.

Comment: @agstudy I can see how it can be a window of 1 too. I thought in a window of 2 since you move every two X-values.

Comment: @LeonLara Ok. I edit the answer. Size is 2 now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

```
test <- data.frame(one=c(2,2,2,3,4,5,5,6),two=c(3,4,5,1,2,1,2,8))
window.size <- 2
test$window.mean <- ave(
                          test$two,
                          findInterval(
                            test$one, 
                            seq(min(test$one),max(test$one),window.size)
                          )
                        )
aggregate(window.mean ~ one, data=test, FUN=head, 1)

  one window.mean
1   2    3.250000
2   3    3.250000
3   4    1.666667
4   5    1.666667
5   6    8.000000
```

To give some explanation of how this works:

If you define some cut points in this example using a window of 2 as:

```
> seq(min(test$one),max(test$one),2)
[1] 2 4 6
```

Then `findInterval` just labels the groups between the defined cut points.

```
> findInterval(test$one,seq(min(test$one),max(test$one),2))
[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3
> test$one
[1] 2 2 2 3 4 5 5 6
```

`ave` just calculates a mean of the first argument within the groups defined by the second argument. So for this example using the groups from `findInterval` and the values from `test$two`, you end up with:

```
#groups 
[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3
#values
[1] 3 4 5 1 2 1 2 8

mean(c(3,4,5,1)) = 3.25
mean(c(2,1,2))   = 1.66
mean(c(8))       = 8
```

Comment: excellent use of `findInterval` , I forget about it +1

Comment: thanks for your answer, it is exactly what I wanted, I'm sorry for the confusion at the beginning. Could you explain me if you can how the combination of ave and findInterval works? thanks!

Comment: @LeonLara - No problems, I have given some more explanation. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Here a `data.table` solution , using `findInterval` but with `data.table` syntax sugar :

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(dat)
window.size <- 2
DT[, m:= mean(V2), findInterval(V1, seq(min(V1),max(V1),window.size))]
   V1 V2        m
1:  2  3 3.250000
2:  2  4 3.250000
3:  2  5 3.250000
4:  3  1 3.250000
5:  4  2 1.666667
6:  5  1 1.666667
7:  5  2 1.666667
8:  6  8 8.000000
```

**The idea**: Create a new grouping variable (By part of data.table) using `findInterval` and calculate the `mean` of coordinates y according to this new grouping variable.

**EDIT** aggregate the result:

```
DT[, list(unique(V1),value = mean(V2)),
   findInterval(V1, seq(min(V1),max(V1),window.size))]

   findInterval V1    value
1:            1  2 3.250000
2:            1  3 3.250000
3:            2  4 1.666667
4:            2  5 1.666667
5:            3  6 8.000000
```

Comment: Is there an `aggregate` equivalent in `data.table` that could be applied here as well?

Comment: @thelatemail I don't know very well `aggregate`, but does my edit make sense?